# Find number of integers in list smaller than a given value

Tags: performance, search

I'm given a list of around 500000 integers, which may contain duplicate values. Given some (other) integer k, I'd like to be able to produce the number of integers in the list that are strictly less than k and the number greater than k.

I could sort the list and use binary search - either twice, one for each result, or once, and then crawl up the list until I find the first value that is greater than k. This will take roughly log_2(500000) ~ 19 operations. I need to do this operation about half a million times.

Is there a better way of structuring the data points so as to make the operation faster? I'm open to pretty much anything, including associative arrays or anything else. I'm implementing in Python most likely, but this is more of a data structuring question than a programming question.

Comment: "I need to do this operation about half a million times."  What "operation" are you referring to?

Comment: @ScottHunter The operation of taking an integer k and searching the given (fixed) list as described.

Comment: "I need to do this operation about half a million times." does this mean you have all the k_i at the start? If so, sort the k_i and then use two pointers, one for each sorted array and you get all the results in a single pass. It's cache friendly too.

Comment: @SimonGoater You should write that up as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @SimonGoater Very fast. Thanks. Learned something here.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a fixed list L of 500,000 integers. Given another list of integers K, you want a fast way to obtain all the results for each of the k_i in that list. A result is two numbers g_i and l_i for each of the k_i where g_i represents the number of integers in L strictly greater than k_i, and l_i is the number of numbers in L strictly less than k_i. How to tackle this problem efficiently depends on how many values are in the list K. Because in this case, there are 'about half a million' integers in the list K, looking up each one in turn may not be efficient, even if the list L were sorted, or in some binary search tree etc. The 'Hash Map' for L might be the modern way to tackle this kind of problem, but not in this case as we can't assume all the elements in K are in L, and even this might be inferior in practice to the traditional 'sort and match' solution below because of the way memory cache works, though only benchmarking would prove this. In any case, the performance would be dependent on the cache architecture of the hardware used. The 'sort and match' approach is the old-fashioned way to tackle this problem as it was common for 'batch' mainframe programs to process sequential files this way as memory was typically too small and slow to do it any other way.

My suggestion is sort both lists K and L in ascending order say, so you've got ordered lists KS and LS. A comparison sort can do it in O(nlog n) time, but integers can be sorted with radix sort also which is O(mn) where m is the width of the 'key'. In practice, it may or may not be faster then other sorting algorithms.

To get all the results, just run two pointers (or indexes) one over each list performing a 'match' operation so the two pointers keep 'in-step'. The pointer on LS advances until it meets a number greater or equal to the element currently pointed to in KS. This gives you the l_i result for this element. Once it reaches a number greater than k_i, or the end of the list, you have h_i. Advance to the next k_i. Repeat until the full list is processed.

If sorting is done with an O(nlog n) algorithm, then processing the arrays is O(n) so overall it is O(nlog n). If radix sort is used, it would be O(n), though is also proportional to the key size. Individual lookups in a binary search tree, or binary chop of a sorted list is also O(nlog n) but darts about all over the list which in practice can be slow because only a small amount of the list can exist in fast cache at any one time. The space requirements depend on the sorting algorithm used. The lists could be sorted in place, keeping the space requirements to a minimum. This 'Sort and Match' method doesn't require that the list L is fixed.

Because in this case there is the same order of magnitude of elements in K as L, results would be found very frequently whilst traversing the two sorted lists which I suspect would make this method hard to beat any other way.

Comment: This works great. If K (or L) has duplicate elements (as my lists do), the algorithm gets a bit more complicated, I think, requiring a nested loop to process elements equal to the current k_i.

Comment: Duplicate k_i values all have the same results, so you can just copy over until you find a greater value. I know it's a bit complicated processing the indexes and edge cases, that's why I only gave a high level description. I suggest you post your code as an answer if you've got a working version.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following code works:

```
a = [2,4,6,7,7,12,12,13,15]
b = [3,5,6,6,7,9,12,12,13,15]
less = [0]*len(a) # number of b's less than each a
gtr = [0]*len(a) # number of b's greater than each a

i = 0
j = 0
while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
  if b[j] < a[i]:
    j += 1
  elif b[j] == a[i]:
    if less[i] <= 0:
      less[i] = j
    j += 1
  else: # b[j] > a[i]
    if less[i] <= 0:
      less[i] = less[i-1] if a[i]==a[i-1] else j
    gtr[i] = len(b)-j
    i += 1
# Get leftover elements from list a
while i < len(a):
  less[i] = len(b)
  gtr[i] = 0
  i += 1

print(less)
print(gtr)
lesscheck = [sum([1 if x > y else 0 for y in b]) for x in a]
gtrcheck = [sum([1 if x < y else 0 for y in b]) for x in a]
assert(less==lesscheck)
assert(gtr==gtrcheck)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work correctly. The indexing for this problem is tricky! It fails for a = [1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 8, 12, 15, 16, 22]
b = [4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]. Your question asks for counts of numbers in b[] STRICTLY less than a[i] right? Then it should print [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 10, ...].

Comment: Fortunately it worked for my dataset. I guess I'll have to go back and figure out this case too. @SimonGoater